# QGIS Graticule at Print Layout starting at from 0

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3, grids-graticules

I would like to add a graticule with coordinates to my map. However, when I add a new grid and modify it the graticule appears but it always starts at 0 and not from its real value.

How could I fix the problem?

All layers are projected in ETRS89/UTM zone 32N.